# fopen - getting a failed to open stream error on an S3 url

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm getting error:

> **Failed to open stream:** HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version not supported

when I try to fopen an Amazon S3 stored file. Not entirely sure what I am doing wrong here.

I am using the following code:

```
$videoPath = s3_site_url("snippets/".$snippet_data->s3_file_name);
//Original URL: https://snipptr.s3.amazonaws.com/snippets/Course%20Intro14378364779608.mp4

$handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<?php

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,"snippets/".$snippet_data->s3_file_name);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

?>
```

and ensure the url you are passing is vaild for CURLOPT_URL

Comment: How do I ensure that?

Comment: echo the url,i.e "snippets/".$snippet_data->s3_file_name